# How can I join non-consecutive partitions on internal hard disk?

Tags: windows-7, partitioning, gparted, clonezilla

I recently installed a new, larger hard disk in my PC at work (the office wouldn't spring for an upgrade for my 75GB disk, so I brought my own 2TB disk in from home). I managed to clone the original drive using CloneZilla, but now I have a 75GB partition on my new drive, followed by a 300MB partition, followed by a 1794.65GB of unallocated space. What I want is to add the unallocated space to the 75GB partition, thereby maximizing my C: drive.

However, when I right-click on the C: partition, the option to "Extend Volume" is grayed out. How do I get all my fancy new extra space to be part of my C: drive? I also tried booting with GParted, but I get the same deal - cannot adjust the C: drive because there's no contiguous space.

Comment: You cannot.  Space must be consecutive.   I think some tools will allow you to relocate your other partition towards the end of the drive?

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is just create a new partition of the remaining space and "`mount`" them in a specific folder on your 75GB Partition. That means the space on your partition would still remain at 75GB but as soon as you move into that folder you wold access the huge remaining space.

You can for example mount the new partition in `c:\data` and then install programs and move data to that directory. All files and subdirectories will be saved on the new partition.

See
http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/11253-mount-drives-partitions-folder.html

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't help me. I need the extra space to install applications, and in my experience applications don't react well to not being installed on the primary hard drive (i.e the one with Windows).

This is a ridiculous problem to have; people upgrade to larger hard drives all the time, no?

Comment: I use thus setup since ever and had never problems installing programs to other drives. Unfortunately, windows still isn't able to edit partition tables in the way you would need to. New installs just create the system-partition first so that the unallocated space comes directly after the 'real' partition. You can try creating images with dd and then dd to the new drive in a different order, but i don't know if that works.